# Geckofx45 Webrtc Signaling fails from different network

Tags: javascript, c#, firefox, webrtc, geckofx

I am trying  P2P signaling from rtcpeerconnection in JavaScript in GeckoFX the app is working fine when signaling is done on the same network but if it's between two different networks there is no any stun sent from the app

Comment: There is now a GeckoFX 60 release: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0

Comment: Great news Thanks! you can also use XulFx it's based on Firefox 52 which has this bug fixed:

https://bitbucket.org/vmas/xulfx/src/default/

and you can download releases from here :

https://bitbucket.org/vmas/xulfx/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Every `RTCPeerConnection` would require a STUN or TURN server if on different networks.

```
var servers = [
    "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
    "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
    "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
    "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
    "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302"
];

var configuration = {
   'iceServers': [{ // sequence<RTCIceServer>
      'urls': servers
   }],
   'iceTransportPolicy': 'all', // default
   'bundlePolicy': 'balanced',  // default
   'rtcpMuxPolicy': 'require'   // default
};

var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

Every time a local session description is set via `setLocalDescription()`,
`onicecandidate` event handler gets triggered with the ICE Candidate.

Comment: Thanks for the response .. but I tried but still not working .. I am using GeckoFx which is based on FireFox 45 .. it has a bug which blocks generating reflexive candidates if I didn't add servers and I think this is the problem .. do you have any Fix for That?

Comment: @Ebram, what do you mean "blocks generating reflexive candidates"? `onicecandidate` event handler was never called?

Answer (score 0):

Adding trun in iceServers will fix it.

or You can use XulFx it's based on Firefox 52 which has this bug fixed:

https://bitbucket.org/vmas/xulfx/src/default/

and you can download releases from here :

https://bitbucket.org/vmas/xulfx/downloads/